# I want to sign into a different App Store account but keep the same Account in FaceTime

Tags: apple-id

If I Sign out of the Apple App Store, will it sign out of my Facetime too?

Answer (score 2):

The account signed in to iTunes & App Store is independent to FaceTime and iMessage. You can freely log out of one without affecting the other.